# IBM visual recognition model

Tags: ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I had created a visual recognition model instance on ibm cloud lite account. But suddenly , one day it started showing 'Inactive' status.Can any one suggest me about how to make it active again?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons for your service being inactive

1. You account can be inactive as `Lite` plan has [limitations](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#liteaccount)- [Inactive  message](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-ts_accnt_inactive)
2. You may have reached the capacity of Visual recognition service as mentioned on the [service creation page](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/visual-recognition)

1,000 Events per month towards:

- Pre-trained model classification
- (General, Food, Explicit) (images) Custom Model classification
- (images) Custom Model training (images)
- 2 Custom Models
- 1 Lite Plan instance per IBM Cloud Organization
- Free Exports to Core ML

Do check your Lite account validity. If it's expired, you can [upgrade the account](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-upgrading-account) and retain the services.

Additionally, if you have created a Visual recognition **machine learning** model. This is a known issue and listed in the [documentation here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/known-issues.html)

> A deployment that is inactive (no scores) for a set time (24 hours for
> the free plan or 120 hours for a paid plan) is automatically
> hibernated. When a new scoring request is submitted, the deployment is
> reactivated and the score request is served. Expect a brief delay of 1
> to 60 seconds for the first score request after activation, depending
> on the model framework.